# Chow group of UFD is trivial?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, divisors-algebraic-geometry, toric-geometry, algebraic-cycles

In literature I saw the word "Chow group problem" coming up, questioning under what conditions the Chow Group is trivial ($=0$). In general this seems to be quite a difficult question.

What is if the given variety is known well? Let $k$ be a algebraically closed field, we can take e.g. $k=\mathbb{C}$. Given the torus $T_N=\text{Spec } k[x_1^{\pm 1}, ..., x_n^{\pm 1}]$ of a $n$-dimensional toric variety can we conclude that the chow groups $CH_{k}(T_N)=0$ for $0< k < n-1$ (or even for $k=0$ or $k=n$)? Does this hold - if at all - in general for spectra of UFD? I have no clue how to start a proof nor how to construct a counterexample

The case $k=n-1$ is already covered as $CH_{n-1}(T_N)=Cl(T_N) =0$.

Comment: Chow groups, except for the dimension, of affine spaces are zero and thus zero for any open set in affine space. Of course chow group for dimension is just integers in this case.

Comment: That's helpful! But why are chow groups of affine spaces always zero? Do you have a reference for that?

Comment: There are many proofs. Simplest may be using the chow group of projective spaces, which is $\mathbb{Z}$ in every dimension generated by a linear subspace.

Comment: Okay. You said that it's zero for any open set in affine space. If we now have a projective variety (say $\mathbb{P}^n$) with torus $T_N \subset \mathbb{P}^n$. Does $CH_k(T_N)=0$ still hold even as $T_N$ is now an open set in projective space? I would say yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question:** "In literature I saw the word "Chow group problem" coming up, questioning under what conditions the Chow Group is trivial (=0)."

**Answer:** There are some methods available to calculate Chow groups (and grothendieck groups). In the case of  a non-singular curve $C$ over an algebraicallg closed field $k$ there is an isomorphism

$$\phi:K_0(C)\cong Pic(C) \oplus \mathbb{Z} \cong CH^*(C)$$

defined by $\phi([E]):=(det(E), rk(E))$ for a locally trivial rank $r$ sheaf $E$. Here $det(E):=\wedge^r E$.

Here $K_0(C)$ is the grothendieck group of $C$ and $CH^*(C)$ is the Chow group.
There is moreover for any $X$ that is "regular in codimension one" (and noetherian, integral, separated and locally factorial) an isomorphism

$$Pic(X \times_k \mathbb{A}^1_k) \cong Pic(X).$$

Hence

$$Pic(\mathbb{A}^n_k) \cong Pic(Spec(k))\cong \mathbb{Z}$$

hence

$$I1.\text{  }\phi:K_0(\mathbb{A}^1_k) \cong CH^*(\mathbb{A}^1_k)\cong  \mathbb{Z}.$$

It is a classical result that projective modules on polynomial rings are free, hence the map in $I1$ is the following map: Let $E:=k[x]\{e_1,..,e_r\}$ be a free $k[x]$-module. It follows $det(E):=\wedge^r E \cong k[x]e_1\wedge \cdots \wedge e_r$ is the free rank one module on $e_1\wedge \cdots \wedge e_r$.
By definition

$$\phi([E]):= (det(E), r) \in (e)\oplus \mathbb{Z}$$

since $Pic(\mathbb{A}^1_k)\cong (e)$ is the trivial group. Since any finite rank projective module on the polynomial ring $A:=k[x_1,..,x_n]$ is free it follows

$$K_0(\mathbb{A}^n_k) \cong \mathbb{Z}.$$

Similarly
$$ CH^*(\mathbb{A}^n_k)=\mathbb{Z}.$$

You will find some of these questions discussed in Hartshorne, Chapter II.6.

**Note:** Exercise HH.II.6.10 proves that $K_0(C) \cong Pic(C) \oplus \mathbb{Z}$ for any such $C$. You should consult this exercise.

**Question:** "Is the Chow group of a UFD is trivial?"

**Answer:** By the isomorphism in $I1$: No.

Comment: Thanks for your guidance and your answer. But if I see this correctly we get $CH^*(\mathbb{A}^n) = \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$ as well. Does this mean that all $CH^i(\mathbb{A}^n)=0$ if $i\neq0$ and $i\neq n$? For general UFD can we get some restrictions for the graded parts $CH^k$ of $CH^*$ with $k\neq n$?

Comment: In Gathmann script I saw that $CH^*(\mathbb{A}^n) = \mathbb{Z}$ as only for $k=n$ we have a non-trivial Chow-group. How does this work out with your solution?

Comment: As far as I know $Pic(\mathbb{A}^n)=0$. After $\oplus \mathbb{Z}$ that would give us correctly $CH^*(\mathbb{A}^n)=\mathbb{Z}$ as well, right?

Comment: Given these theorems (which are given for general UFD) would also give us $K_0(C)=CH^*(C)=\mathbb{Z}$ for such a $C$, right?

Comment: @LegNaiB - you are correct.

Comment: So does $CH^*(X)\simeq \mathbb{Z}$ imply that $CH^i=0$ for all $i > 0$ and $CH^0(X)\simeq\mathbb{Z}$? Because we always have $CH^0(X) = \mathbb{Z}[X]$ right? If we know that $CH^*(X)=\mathbb{Z}$ that means that all other gradings (besides that for $0$) have to be $0$?